# \vspace* adds unwanted page in amsbook

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting, amsbook, vspace

**Background:** I'm using the `amsbook` environment, and the title created by `\tableofcontents` starts near the first quarter of the page by default. I've been trying to move it up by placing a `\vspace{-3in}` before `\tableofcontents`, but it didn't do anything. Then I tried `\vspace*{-3in}` and not only did it not work, it also inserted two blank pages (or 1, if I use the `oneside` parameter for `amsbook`) before the table of contents. I tested it with positive numbers too and observed the same behaviour.

Everything worked, however, when I changed from `amsbook` to `article`.

**Question**: How I can use `vspace` with a negative value to move my table of contents up in the `amsbook` environment, without creating new pages. My table of contents is supposed to start on a new page.

**Other things I've tried:** Instead of using a plain `\vspace` right before `\tableofcontents`, I've also tried

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc}{\clearpage\vspace{-3in}\@starttoc}{}{}
```

which also didn't do anything, and created a new page when I added the `*`.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
  \vspace{-3in}
  \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

Both of the code blocks above produced this

[image: a page with a blank toc]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}

\begin{document}
  \vspace*{-3in}
  \tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

This produced

[image: three blank pages with a blank toc]

Comment: the table of contents starts in the same place as other unnumbered chapters (try with `\chapter*{something}`). To change this you would have to adapt `\@makeschapterhead`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer Thank you for replying. I understanding this is diverging from the original question, but since I'm quite new to latex, do you mind elaborating or providing a link on how I can adapt `\@makeschapterhead` to move my table of contents up please?

Comment: Why do you  use the class if you don't like their design decisions? It is rather special and adapted to the ams needs. A class like book or scrbook or memoir can be changed more easily.

Comment: I like all of the other stylings that amsbook has. The only design in amsbook I want to change is the toc top margin. I thought it would be easier to change this one thing than to change the styling of everything else like the chapter, section, subsection... etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to treat the chapters initiated by `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables` in a different fashion.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsbook}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for showing the placement

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@starttoc}{\@makeschapterhead}{\special@makeschapterhead}{}{}
\let\special@makeschapterhead\@makeschapterhead
\xpatchcmd{\special@makeschapterhead}{7.5pc}{0pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Test title}

\end{document}
```

I use `oneside` just to show the relative placements in a smaller picture; also `showframe` is used to display the text block boundaries.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this. It will affect all unnumbered chapter! Adapt the 10pt to your needs.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@makeschapterhead{7.5pc}{10pt}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \chapter*{something}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked, and luckily I don't have any other unnumbered chapters :) Sorry I can't upvote you as I don't have 15 reputation yet.